# Trying to understand the Binary Insertion Sort?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

Could anyone please tell me how this code sorts the array? i don't get it! and how is this code reducing the complexity of a regular insertion sort?

```
// Function to sort an array a[] of size 'n'
void insertionSort(int a[], int n)
{
    int i, loc, j, k, selected;

    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        j = i - 1;
        selected = a[i];

        // find location where selected sould be inseretd
        loc = binarySearch(a, selected, 0, j);

        // Move all elements after location to create space
        while (j >= loc)
        {
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j+1] = selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, i got the code from " http://geeksquiz.com/binary-insertion-sort/ "

Answer (score 2):

This code uses the fact that the portion of the array from zero, inclusive, to `i`, exclusive, is already sorted. That's why it can run  `binarySearch` for the insertion location of `a[i]`, rather than searching for it linearly.

This clever trick does not change the asymptotic complexity of the algorithm, because the part where elements from `loc` to `i` are moved remains linear. In the worst case (which happens when the array is sorted in reverse) each of the `N` insertion steps will make `i` moves, for a total of N(N-1)/2 moves.

The only improvement that this algorithm has over the classic insertion sort is the number of comparisons. If comparisons of objects being sorted are computationally expensive, this algorithm can significantly reduce the constant factor.

Comment: well, if your data structure is not an array/list, but a skiplist for example, binary search will make your complexity O(n * log(n)), because inserts/deletes will be constant and binary search will be O(log(n))